# PHP - How can I check if a string contains only lower case characters?

Tags: php

How can I check if a string in php contains    only lower case characters?

I tried:

```
        if (!preg_match('~[a-z]~', $_POST['name'])) 
        {
          $errors[] = 'Caracteres inapropriados!';
         }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're only matching against a single lower case character: if you use preg_match, then search for multiple characters, and anchor the beginning and end of the string `~^[a-z]+$~`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

It return's true if all characters are lower case!

```
if(ctype_lower($_POST['name']))
    echo "All characters are lower case!";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you're wanting to use regular expressions -

```
if (!preg_match('^[a-z]+$', $_POST['name']))...
```

Comment: Thanks! But ctype_lower was better in my case. But thanks anyway

Comment: +1 *Oh,* and I doubt you'd of gotten a green ticky, unless instructing the OP (*doesn't seem to know/aware of how Stack ticks, pardon the pun*). I don't see a green ticky for the other answer that the OP said had liked better.  But, your answer does indeed answer the originally posted question/code.

Comment: @Minearenasurporte Jay answered the question correctly as per your posted and broken code. You did not specify for additional options.